# export section to pdf in view in laravel using javascript

Tags: javascript, laravel, pdf, jspdf

I have a section in an interface in Laravel that I want to export to pdf. I used javascript to do that
But I have a problem with the Arabic language, as the letters become separated, why?

**this is the code section**

```
<section id="report">
        <div class="navbar-light" style="padding: 20px">
            {{-- sectionReport1 header --}}
            <nav>
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="paddingPartNav col-5 justify-content-center align-items-center">
                            <p class="info"><strong>Arab Specialized Company For Industry</strong></p>
                            <p class="numCall">Riyadh
                                -C.R.:1010770277&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Vat
                                No.:311217948200003</p>
                            <div class=" max stybrleft"></div>

                        </div>
                        <div class="col-2 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
                            <img class="imagerepo" src="{{ asset('images/logo/logo.png') }}" alt="image description">
                        </div>
                        <div class="paddingPartNav col-5 justify-content-center align-items-center">
                            <p class="info"><strong>Content for the third div Industry</strong></p>
                            <p class="numCall">1010770277: الرياض-س.ت&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;:
                                311217948200003&nbsp;الرقم
                                الضربي</p>
                            <div class=" max stybrleft"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
<section>
```

**this is the code javascript**

```
function exportSectionToPDF() {
            // Get the section element
            const section = document.getElementById('report');

            // Create a configuration object for html2pdf
            const config = {
                filename: 'section.pdf',
                margin: [10, 0, 10, 0],
                image: {
                    type: 'jpeg',
                    quality: 0.98
                },
                html2canvas: {
                    scale: 2,
                },
                jsPDF: {
                    unit: 'mm',
                    format: 'a4',
                    orientation: 'portrait',
                    putOnlyUsedFonts: true,
                    floatPrecision: 16,
                    mode: 'utf8',
                    encoding: 'UNICODE',
                    fonts: [{
                        family: 'Droid Arabic Kufi',
                        src: 'url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/ea/droidarabickufi/v6/DroidKufi-Regular.ttf)'
                    }]
                }
            };

            // Modify the content of the <p> element to include the RTL direction
            const paragraph = section.querySelector('p');
            const originalText = paragraph.innerText;
            paragraph.innerText = '\u202B' + originalText; // Prepend the RTL control character

            html2pdf().set(config).from(section).save();

            paragraph.innerText = originalText;
        }
```

**this is the view befor the export**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MqSkU.png)
[image]

**this is the pdf view when i click button export to pdf**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTcsv.png)
[image]